# Prevent Angular removing = after # in URL?

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-routing

We have a hybird AngularJS-Angular application. We have "sibling router" setup whereby each router is aware of which paths belong to it and will render a blank component for any route that does not belong to it.

The AngularJS application will navigate to pages by passing query params after the `#`, such as: `index.jsp#/r=page.go/route`. However, Angular is removing everything after the `=`. This causes a routing event in AngularJS, making it navigate to `/r` instead of `/r=page.go/route` and breaks the page.

We had hoped to override this behaviour in the Angular router. However, when we log the `NavigationStart` event the path Angular sees is `/r`- so the problem has already occurred before the very first navigation event we can hook into. Is there any way to change this behaviour?

Comment: Not 100% sure but I'm pretty sure that using an `=` in url outside of params is illegal. You could try using the url encoding for `=` which is `%3D`

Comment: It is invalid URL syntax, I agree with you there. Problem we have is that AngularJS supported it and it has been used in numerous places across an enormous legacy application, so we need to support the syntax one way or another  Think I may have found a way though, will update with an answer if it works

Answer (score 1):

`=` is a [reserved character](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2). You cannot use it in that part of the url, only in the query params section.

You could try encoding it as `%3D` like so: `/r%3Dpage.go/route`.